# Typescript not inferring type from outer function

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Is there a way to help the compiler to infer something like the following:

```
class Base<T> {
    children(... children: (A<any> | B<T>)[]) { return this }
    onVisit(handler:(context: T)=>void) { return this }
}

class A<T> extends Base<T> {
    constructor( public context: T ) { super() }
}

class B<T> extends Base<T> {}

const foo = new A({ bar: 1 })
    .children(
        new A({baz:2}).onVisit(({baz})=>{}),
        new B().onVisit(({bar})=>{}) // Fails here because it infers that the instance as type B<unknown> instead of B<{bar:number}>
    )
```

It doesn't seem to be because the compiler can't draw some context from the calling function since this works:

```
function f1<T>(p: T, ...h: ((p:T) => void)[]) { }
function f2<T>(h: (p: T) => void) { return h }

f1({ a: 1 }, 
    f2((p) => { console.log(p.a) }),
)
```

I might be totally confused (very likely) but it seems like if the latter works so should the former.

Comment: This is because when you create `new B()` this will create a B<unknown>. The compiler will first analyse this before looking at the `onVisit`. So you need to provide the type parameter when creating `B`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but why doesn't the compiler instantiate the function in the second example as `f2<unknown>`? Are constructors treated differently for some reason, or am I misunderstanding the difference between the different scenraios?

Comment: The constructor in your first example has no parameters, so there is no way to infer the type. In your second example, parameters of `f2` are inferred because in definition of `f1`, you defined that they are the same `T` for both parameters.

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret: facepalm: right. of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Normal" type inference in TypeScript happens when the compiler examines the *contents* of a expression to determine what type it is.  It looks *inside* the expression to do this. This tends to happen in the same direction as control flow of the emitted program at runtime.  If I have code like

```
let x = ""; 
let y = x.length;
```

, the compiler determines the type of `""` (which will be `""`), and uses that to determine the type of `x` (which will be `string`).  Then the compiler determines the type of `x.length` by checking the type of the `length` property on `string` (which will be `number`), and then uses this to determine the type of `y` (which will be `number`).  Earlier expressions determine the types of later expressions.

However, there are a few situations where the compiler does [*contextual typing*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing). In contextual typing, inference happens when the compiler examines the *context* of an expression to determine what type it is.  It looks *outside* the expression to do this.  This tends to happen in the *opposite* direction of the control flow of the emitted program at runtime.  If I have code like

```
[""].map(z => z.length)
```

, the variable `z` inside the callback has no explicit typing, but its type cannot be determined by examining the contents of the callback.  However, the since the `map()` method of an array of `string` values *expects* its argument to be a callback that takes a `string` property, the compiler uses this *context* to give `z` the type of `string`.  Here, in some sense, a later expression is used to determine the type of an earlier expression.

But contextual typing is fragile.  It only happens in a few special circumstances, and is easily broken by making the necessary contextual information "father away" from the expression whose type needs to be inferred:

```
let cb = z => z.length; // error, z is implicitly any
[""].map(cb); // oops, now we have an any[]
```

Here the same callback, `z => z.length` is being created.  But it is happening by itself.  The only place it is used is as a callback to a `string[]`'s `map()` method.  So technically the compiler could *conceivably* say, "well, `cb` is expected to be a callback of a type like `(val: string) => any`, and therefore we go up one line and give `cb` that type, and then from that context we can infer that `z` must be a `string`.  But this does not happen.  Inference fails.

---

One place contextual typing happens is inferring the type parameter of a called generic function by using the expected return type for context.  Your `f2()` situation does this, similar to this:

```
declare function f<T>(): T;
const numGood: number = f(); // infers number for T
```

The function `f()` claims to return a value of any possible type `T`. One could never infer `T` from a call to `f()` in the "normal" way because there's nothing about `f()` to tell you what `T` should be.  But contextually, the compiler expects it to return a `number` because `numGood` is annotated as `number`.  And so it works.  This actually can be propagated backward through multiple function calls, as long as the type mapping is straightforward:

```
declare function id<T>(x: T): T;
const numGood: number = id(id(id(id(f())))); // infers number for all Ts
```

But, in your `new B().onVisit` situation, you are trying to make the compiler contextually infer a function's (or, rather, a constructor call's) type parameter given the type of a *property* (or, rather, a method) of its return value.  This apparently breaks contextual inference.  It's similar to this:

```
declare function g<T>(): { a: T };
const numBad: number = g().a; // error!
```

The function `g()` returns a value of type `{a: T}`.  Even though `g().a` is being used in a context that expects a `number`, this apparently does not propagate backwards to the call site of `g()`.  The inference fails. `T` defaults to `unknown`, and you get an error.

---

I can't point to a particular GitHub issue or documentation that outlines when you can and cannot expect contextual typing to work.  There are near misses, like [microsoft/TypeScript#29771](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29771) which describes some situations at the limits of compiler's ability to perform contextual typing.  But I haven't yet seen a canonical answer that says "`f2` yes, `new B().onVisit` no".

Barring that, if you run into a situation where type inference fails you, consider manually annotating or specifying the types yourself.  If you don't want `new B()` to produce a `B<unknown>`, then write `new B<{bar: number}>()` and it should start working.   Tedious?  Sure.  But at least it works!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.5#code/DYUwLgBAHhC8ECIEG4KkgTztAdKAdgOZgAWyAUJQNpIC6OAtgIYAOAFAF5wB8EHeIIqQCUFcuggBjAEbYusXvwLEyEAPRqIIAE7aA9toA0fCAEsAzmYYtgpyabDAsTfBnI0E9ZuxmjKAExBJYCZtEAgAMwBXfEkwUz18M38AHgAVbjYoAC4INOFctIpA4NDw6Nj4xMj0zIK8iklE80h8KIYAcT09f1y2hmkdbFN-NhGx0fGItmFZ2dQNM3wInUsAoJCwyJi4hKTCWpncgG8IJkKIAF9G5tb2gCEmXoh+we1sQhmcJjEgA)