# Typescript: infer type from child to parent function

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I've got a factory function that takes an `onError` function as an option. 
The factory returns a "child" function that has it's own options. 
Based on the options of the "child" function, a different type should be inferred to the factory's `onError` option \

In my specific case:

- when the child function has a `schema` option, `onError` arg should be inferred `Error | SchemaError`
- when the child function has no `schema` option, `onError` arg should just be inferred `Error`

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
interface SchemaError {
   schemaError: any
}

interface CreateFetchClientConfig<E> {
    onError: (error:E) => any
}

interface FetchClientConfig {
    schema?: any
}

const createFetchClient =<E = any> ({onError}: CreateFetchClientConfig<E>)=>{
    function fetchClient({schema}: FetchClientConfig) {
        if(schema){
            /* infer onError: (error: Error | SchemaError) => void */
        }
        else {
            /* infer onError: (error: Error) => void */
        }
    }
    return fetchClient
}

const fetchClient1 = createFetchClient({
    onError(error){
        /* typeof error = Error */
    }
})

fetchClient1({})


const fetchClient2 = createFetchClient({
    onError(error){
        /* typeof error = Error | SchemaError */
    }
})

fetchClient2({ schema: {})
```

I doubt this is even doable, but any help is welcome

Comment: Does this depend on zod? If so you might want to tag it as such. If not, then you might want to [edit] the code to remove any third-party dependencies so that it's a proper [mre].

Comment: @jcalz thanks for your answer, I edited the post to remove any reference to zod.

Comment: And yet there's still `z.array(z.string())`, which is a reference to... what?  Can you define `z`?

Comment: @jcalz schema can be anything, I replaced it by an empty object

Comment: So, I'm not sure how you expect this to work... seems like you want some sort of backwards-in-time inference of the function type based on how it's called later.  If you write `const f = createFetchClient({onError(e) {})`, what should `e` be inferred to be?  Does it depend on if someone calls `f({})` vs `f({schema:{}})`? What if someone calls it *both* ways?  If you wanted the reverse inference where you *annotate* `e` and that controls how `f` can be called later, that would be possible.  Are you interested in that?

Comment: (and if you are interested, I'd need to know which calls to allow; I think it would be that if `e` is annotated as just `Error` then you want to prohibit `f()` from sending a defined `schema`... like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/we6YKN) shows.  If that's not right, can you clarify how it should go?)

Comment: "So, I'm not sure how you expect this to work... seems like you want some sort of backwards-in-time inference of the function type based on how it's called later. If you write const f = createFetchClient({onError(e) {}), what should e be inferred to be? Does it depend on if someone calls f({}) vs f({schema:{}})? What if someone calls it both ways?" Yeap tha'ts what I want, if someone calls it both ways `Error | SchemaError` should be inferred

Comment: " If you wanted the reverse inference where you annotate e and that controls how f can be called later, that would be possible. Are you interested in that?"  This would defeat the purpose, I'd rather type the error to `unknown` and force users to type it

Comment: @jcalz To be clear, what error is inferred in `const fetcher = createFetchClient({onError(error) {})` should depend on how you call `fetcher` ( `fetcher({})` vs `fetcher({schema:{}}` )

Comment: I understand what you want, but it's impossible, sorry.

Comment: That's what I feared, thanks anyway

Comment: So would you accept an answer saying that this is impossible? It would be very similar to [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64653179/2887218).

Comment: I can only upvote the comment since there is no answer, feel free to answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better or worse, what you're looking for is impossible in TypeScript.  Generally speaking, [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) works in the same direction as the control flow of the program.  For example, if you call a function with an input and assign the result to a variable, the compiler will *first* try to evaluate the type of the input, *then* it will try to evaluate the type of the output of the function given that input type, and *finally* it will infer that the variable is of that type, which is the same evaluation order that happens at runtime when you do that assignment:

```
declare function f<T>(x: T): T[];
declare const x: number;
const v = f(x);
// const v: number[]
```

There are a very few situations where inference works in the opposite direction of control flow; this is called [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing), where the compiler tries to figure out what the type of some value needs to be in order for some later operation on that value to be of a known type.  For example, a callback parameter type can sometimes be inferred without annotation:

```
declare function g<T>(x: T, cb: (x: T) => void): void;
declare const x: number;
g(x, (x) => console.log(x.toFixed(1)));
// -> ^ (parameter) x: number
```

In the above, the `x` callback parameter is inferred as `number` in response to `g` being called with a numeric first argument, even though at runtime, the callback has to be evaluated before the function call to `g()` is evaluated. The number of places contextual typing works is small, and it is *fragile*.  It's easy to break it by separating the thing you need to infer from the context in which it can be inferred:

```
declare function g<T>(x: T, cb: (x: T) => void): void;
declare const x: number;
const cb = (x) => console.log(x.toFixed(1)); // error
// -------> ~ parameter 'x' implicitly has an any type  
g(x, cb);
```

Even though that's the same callback as before, inference breaks; the compiler cannot "see" that the callback parameter needs to be of type `number` in order for the call `g(x, cb)` to make sense.  Once you assign the callback to a variable, the compiler needs to infer a type for that variable; so the inference goes back to the old way of trying to fully evaluate the type of the initializer and then assigning that type to the `cb` variable.

And it can't do that.  Instead it gives up and falls back to [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) and [warns about it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#noimplicitany).

The only supported way to proceed here would be to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) the callback parameter explicitly in advance, so that the compiler can at least type check the code:

```
declare function g<T>(x: T, cb: (x: T) => void): void;
declare const x: number;
const cb = (x: number) => console.log(x.toFixed(1)); // okay
g(x, cb);
```

Now things work because you're not asking the compiler to predict the future of where `cb` might be called.

---

This is analogous to your example code: you want

```
const fetchClient = createFetchClient({
  onError(error) {}
})

fetchClient(arg)
```

to be able to determine the type of the `error` callback parameter from the fact that `fetchClient` *will eventually* be called with a certain argument.  But the compiler needs to know the type of `fetchClient` *before* it can evaluate the type of `fetchClient(arg)`, and by assigning the result of `createFetchClient()` to the `fetchClient` variable, the compiler needs to evaluate the types of the arguments to `createFetchClient` *before* it can evaluate the type of `fetchClient`.  The inference supported by the compiler here is in the forwards-in-time direction, but your code only works as desired if it could do so backwards.  Which it can't (see [ms/TS#48138](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48138) for example).

---

So what can you do? Well the only real way forward is to just accept that inference can't happen here and annotate your callback parameter yourself.  Then the compiler could possibly narrow the type of `fetchClient` and only allow you to call it with certain arguments.  So if you make a mistake in your annotation, you'll catch the error later.  This is the reverse of what you're asking for, but it has the benefit of being possible:

```
const createFetchClient = <E extends SchemaError | Error>(
  { onError }: CreateFetchClientConfig<E>
) => {
  function fetchClient({ schema }: 
    E extends SchemaError ? { schema: any } : { schema?: undefined }
  ) { }
  return fetchClient
}

const fetchClient1 = createFetchClient({
  onError(error: Error) { }
})
fetchClient1({}) // okay
fetchClient1({ schema: {} }); // error

const fetchClient2 = createFetchClient({
  onError(error: Error | SchemaError) { }
})
fetchClient2({}); // okay
fetchClient2({ schema: {} }); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-boNEFEkQAPsgxFQO0ZAmCArk0awYgSAZARBBxXHaDx358fx+6gg6MCGYpxmWB5UQMD5LkWVZIA2Wg5HeTE5DqfZ8ScDRyCsElGmsLUJSaCAvI0Y4EX8U2MAysluANcYTXUMcABUuGxaQgmUdYQl2EJyDOXZDCud+-pbj1xydfxvBdRZCg0CgjVdb1-XQJ5rlWKJY3mLNWLIAtS1SUtK38eIXxQDFcVBeA2l8Osb6xYFSlgPyex6f5LFPd9iVLUNJAjSd+U3dw9hvVUQPGfyiUw+q72hvDX3GQATH9+mA5jHEg01YNQBDJAdatO0jmORAtaJezeZNOXjRdTXQ7DxifUZHFY4lBUMGV3D1SM85akuKCoHS1TRduul4wpz0mWZeDpZAmW2cz5gTS5Qnuft43cL58sI8FoShQY4VLVF9oY9z4B821cCpSrllq1lU1EeNeXlYVVElWV-OxJVmUQDVdUw1DS13dUD22-FHGva+6Nc-H4C-aZ-3MQrwNbSTZNiUJFPLdpsPUCnitI2QEeikQUHUeX32V4HcCC8LEGiXDD4N9juMA9nCW515Qn58dTnZfZM1qeznMm+AvNV+BNd1zPBNzw75GtzDQwQbX0EPEAA)