# How to get TypeScript to accept disjunct type in map?

Tags: typescript

When I try this:

```
type DataKey = string
type DataValue = {type:'A',a:string} | {type:'B',b:number}
type ObjType = {data: Map<DataKey,DataValue>}

const obj: ObjType = {data: new Map}

fpShallowMerge<ObjType>({
    data: fpMapSet('b', {
        type: 'B',
        b: 55,
    })
})
```

TypeScript gives an error:

```
Type '(map: nil | Map<string, { type: "B"; b: number; }>) => Map<string, { type: "B"; b: number; }>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, DataValue> | ((args_0: Map<string, DataValue>, args_1: "data") => Map<string, DataValue>) | undefined'.
  Type '(map: nil | Map<string, { type: "B"; b: number; }>) => Map<string, { type: "B"; b: number; }>' is not assignable to type '(args_0: Map<string, DataValue>, args_1: "data") => Map<string, DataValue>'.
    Types of parameters 'map' and 'args_0' are incompatible.
      Type 'Map<string, DataValue>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, { type: "B"; b: number; }>'.
        Type 'DataValue' is not assignable to type '{ type: "B"; b: number; }'.
          Property 'b' is missing in type '{ type: "A"; a: string; }' but required in type '{ type: "B"; b: number; }'.(2322)
```

Why does it say "b" is missing? The type is supposed to be A *or* B.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/PTAEBUE0AUFEGUBcBYAUGgpgDwA4HsAnAF1CIE8cNQAlDAZzwBsA3AQwCNGMAecANVaMArlQC8oIQDsA1pLwB3SQBoIAQQIBzOqGxEMkgCbbarA3kmMy6gqzLcpshZIB8ocQG0Auq-H9BInSw9Q21WSTJQAH4IAWEqAB9QAAokgDp01k06RDUsgEo3Vz84gpzJDGYMAjRMXEISADMpAGMiAEtzUAJ6JkrYkV5+jBVwdS1A4KMaDFNzS2tbbjCyZ2cktkYc2gYWDi5B-2HcrWcVdNTMrRzR-Ouh0ABvNFAXrowiIQJJUgoMPAbQBs3KJxAByJqSVodSSgqKAwRpDL5UA5DZoAC+NVQ2HwxFAEKhnQaOHgAAtBIwFABZKoaHjgCb6KYPdFrc54dgAKwwrWyoAWdieqFeoHcAGlQG1vtIMGR-hBPJEtj1dpx6eLPCp3OANSoxd4ANwY5x5HJJDmc64FURFR7PV7dD5fZIWq2FO3CkWvZrmOiNNqMPTdAxuUAWnlEOipBoBoPm914UAAQnEkiEjEYeXtXslDSSSZjgaqGAMqS4kg0RFJBSFOZzjs+3wt2a9mM9OZ9kj9bxI4gA8lyIxc6HQ2hpJEkB9zWqlmt1WHokmmMwVWNoWSoLVn216GoQkp3u4n5YWgyWay26-j94eSNIwwCp0OZWQ6ObV9oBdwX-LwCaPVeV6Ou40ieKG3Q7H0hzmiBYFrqAywqMBoEqNIH4QCBsq-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)

---

[Simplified playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/PTAEBUE0AUFEGUBcBYAUGgpgDwA4HsAnAF1ADMBXAOwGMiBLPS0AWwwIHMMAecUbIjJQAmAZ1ABvAL4A+ABQBDRBAA0oAEZLwASglpQ+0AQxFyBJuIB0V+aqsW1ktI-Sps+YmSq0GTUjgCy8jjwxlwA0qoAanIA1hgAnkoRoABu8gA25BhKkTriegZGJmagssxBSoE44VHSOgC80rqoBq2g1IwiJEWg9aCUGADuoFVlQVoFbYbGFiLGsnHxqmmZGBMtU9PFTEWToM7OaCAQABKwEAjgKC5E8TgYoAAi8kTyYQm9oF0EdJTsaLd7qAAIKfcSA7IAcmBkOUim+v3YzghoAAQmCIYhIajYRpKORmGo2Mi7g9nq9Ihksp9QQAfNEA0mgADyagAVuAmX1xEIXooRkEuOS3gllMLKatpIdUB1KF1QHh2UpWRyuRJea8lANhlVpawOBhZIq2ap8ht9Br+X4qiEiLJIWpYc1NqBMaBsbC9q0NKAAKy+5R7SRaI3siyW9bBoA)

Comment: I'm not sure _why_ it happens, but you can solve it by adding explicit type parameters to `fpMapSet` on line 49: `fpMapSet<DataKey, DataValue>(`

Comment: You're hiding quite a bit of complexity in that playground link; could you put the full [mre] as plaintext in the question itself, and maybe sure that it's minimal (e.g., do you *need* conditional types like `Resolvable` to reproduce the issue?)

Comment: @jcalz I added a new simplified playground link. The key here is that I want to infer the types for `fpMapSet` which I'm starting to think I can't do. I was hoping it would infer from `data:` since I don't think it can infer from the returned function.

Comment: Right, if you're expecting `f(x)(y)` to infer a generic type argument for `f` based on the type of `y`, it's not going to happen.  Contextual typing doesn't reach back through function calls that way.  It's hard to find a canonical explanation for that somewhere; best I can do is something like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64650888/2887218) which is explaining contextual typing and that it's fragile